# Get a jdbc resource from a glassfish server in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, datasource

I am creating a desktop application in Java with *NetBean* and I want to connect with *glassfish server*. This is my code to get the DataSource:

```
private DataSource getDataSourceFromJNDI(String jndiDataSourceName) {
    try {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        p.setProperty(Context.STATE_FACTORIES, "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        p.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(p);
        return (DataSource) ic.lookup(jndiDataSourceName);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        log.error("JNDI error while retrieving " + jndiDataSourceName, e);
        throw new AuthorizationException(e);
    }
}
```

My resource name is: **pooljdnibd**. In my code I set *jdniDataSourceName* in different ways like:

```
java:comp/env/pooljdnibd
java:global/pooljdnibd
java:jdbc/pooljdnibd
jdbc/pooljdnibd
pooljdnibd
```

and all give me an exception:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory]
```

Comment: What do you mean `connect with glassfish server`? You want to get the DataSource from Glassfish? Why? This code will only work inside an EJB container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access Glassfish resources registered in JNDI outside of the Glassfish server in general (that applies to any other Java EE server).

The only resources in JNDI, which you may access, are EJB components, if they have a remote interface. Another option is to create a service over HTTP protocol (any kind of service, such as SOAP or REST), and connect to it. The technique to connect to each kind of service is of course different.

Once you access an EJB or a service running on the server, you may retrieve data from Datasource registered in JNDI. But you need to retrieve **data** from the datasource, not the datasource itself. You would do that by issuing query from within the EJB or service running inside Glassfish, and then return result to the desktop application, which called the service.